# Re-sample from a maximal value sample

Tags: r, statistics, resampling

I have the following question:
I have 4 bags with 20 values in each of them, and I randomly pick a sample of 10 from each of the 4 bags:

```
for (i in 1:20){
  bag1[i] = sample(0:50,1)
  bag2[i] = sample(0:50,1)
  bag3[i] = sample(0:50,1)
  bag4[i] = sample(0:50,1)
}

for (j in 1:10){
    samp=sample(1:20,1)
    bag1value=bag1value+bag1[samp]
    bag2value=bag2value+bag2[samp]
    bag3value=bag3value+bag3[samp]
    bag4value=bag4value+bag4[samp]
}
```

Now, I want to sample again 10 values from the bag that has the **maximal** value in the first sample.  So I can do:

```
maxbag=max(bag1value,bag2value,bag3value,bag4value)   
if (maxbag==bag1value){ 
    for (j1 in 1:10){
      samp=sample(1:20,1)
      secondsample=secondsample+bag1[samp]
    } elseif (maxbag==bag2value){
        samp=sample(1:20,1)
        secondsample=secondsample+bag2[samp]
     }
```

But I am looking for a more elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working at the moment. Arguments j and j1 are not present in the two for-loops deriving bag values and secondsample.

Anyway, the more elegant way of dealing with the data is with a list or an array. The first loop can be replace with the array "bags" below, with columns 1:4 representing bags 1 to 4:

```
bags<-sapply(1:4, function(x) sample(1:50, 20, replace=T))
colnames(bags) <- paste0("bag", 1:4)
head(bags) 

     bag1 bag2 bag3 bag4
[1,]    7    1   14   16
[2,]   50   23   49    7
[3,]   14   48   26   10
[4,]   42   11    8   10
[5,]   31   43   11    9
[6,]    5   20   27   19
```

To pick up the 10 from each bag:

```
new <- sapply(colnames(bags), function(x)sample(bags[,x], 10, replace=F))
head(new)

     bag1 bag2 bag3 bag4
[1,]   14    1   49    2
[2,]   31   26   13   18
[3,]    1   48   14    9
[4,]   38   23   27    6
[5,]   24   23   26   10
[6,]   14   42    8   29
```

To determine which bag contain the maximum value:

```
max.new <- sapply(1:4, function(x) max(new[,x]))
max.new

[1] 38 48 49 29

max.bag <- colnames(bags)[max.new==max(max.new)]
```

Resample of bag with maximum value:

```
secondsample <- sample(bags[,max.bag], 10)
secondsample

[1]  8 13 27 14 31 13 49 29 38  5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how can I do that when I sample, I use the same "row" for each of the bags? For example I decided to sample row [3], the output of the new sample will be (14,48,26,10).

Comment: The bags are in columns, and not rows. You can sample say "bag1", with `sample(bags[,"bag1"],10)`

Comment: There might be a problem with this code in case of a "tie" when choosing the second sample. To avoid this problem I think we should write: secondsample <- sample(bags[,max.bag[1]], 10), or max.bag<-max.bag[sample(1)].